# Does e.g. `mdadm --add` warn before overwriting existing non-RAID data?

Tags: mdadm

In an earlier QA, I noted that some of the `mkfs` tools give you a nice warning if you're about to overwrite an existing filesystem.

`mdadm --add` seems slightly less cautious.  The same command is used for adding a new disk to an array which was created in "degraded" mode (missing redundant disks), and if you add an old disk after testing your system survives a disk removal.

This is mostly idle curiosity, but does `mdadm --add` include any safety-check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mdadm --add` will refuse work on a block device which is already mounted.  (I have not verified that this completely avoids losing any data :).

However it does not check for an existing, non-RAID filesystem.  It doesn't compare RAID UUIDs on RAID partitions either.

Remember to take care when using `mdadm --add` :).  Just like you should with... just about any other command you run with `root` privileges.